# How do I restore one database from a mysqldump containing multiple databases?

Tags: database, import, mysql, restore

I have a mysql dump with 5 databases and would like to know if there is a way to import just one of those (using mysqldump or other).

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is. Importing all databases, and dropping every one except the one you want to keep, is the best thing you can do I think - but you never know, maybe somebody comes up with something

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pipe the dumped SQL through `sed` and have it extract the database for you.  Something like:

```
cat mysqldumped.sql | \
sed -n -e '/^CREATE DATABASE.*`the_database_you_want`/,/^CREATE DATABASE/ p' | \
sed -e '$d' | \
mysql
```

The two `sed` commands:

1. Only print the lines matching between the `CREATE DATABASE` lines (including both `CREATE DATABASE` lines), and
2. Delete the *last* `CREATE DATABASE` line from the output since we don't want mysqld to create a second database.

If your dump does not contain the `CREATE DATABASE` lines, you can also match against the `USE` lines.

Comment: In a single line, and with the `-u` and `-p` options: `cat all-databases.sql | sed -n -e '/^CREATE DATABASE.*\`the_database_you_want\`/,/^CREATE DATABASE/ p' | sed -e '$d' | mysql -u my_username -p`

Answer (score 31):

You can use the mysql command line --one-database option.

```
mysql> mysql -u root -p --one-database YOURDBNAME < YOURFILE.SQL
```

Of course be careful when you do this.

You can also use a [mysql dumpsplitter](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mydumpsplitter-extract-tables-from-mysql-dump-shell-script/comment-page-1/).

Comment: I tried this, but always got the error "ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'redmine'". The documentation states: "This is useful for skipping updates to other databases in the binary log." This is not a binary log (I think) so it wont work.

Comment: I found an interesting bug report relating to this feature: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40477

Comment: @ThePixelDeveloper: An empty database need to exist first, then it works.

Comment: Ah, I finally understood what @RuneKaagaard meant: If you want to restore the "redmine" database, then first log in to mysql as root and do a "CREATE DATABASE redmine". Afterwards the "--one database" command switch will work afterwards.

Comment: Could this be used when I want to import olddbname into newdbname?

Comment: Oracle's documentation cautions against this command. It can easily end up with undexpected results. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_one-database